# How to run multiple applications on one website?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting, web-applications

Hi I am working on a site where I need to run multiple applications (Blogengine.net, nopCommerce, and DotNetNuke) on one website with the same domain name.

How would I go about adding all three applications if I'm using Windows Server 2008(my hosting provider is DiscountASP.net)?

I want to accomplish adding the sites with this format:

- www.sitename.com/webapp1
- www.sitename.com/webapp2
- www.sitename.com/webapp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add virtual directories/applications to your hosting IIS configuration.

Under "Tools & Utilities" choose "Web Application Tool".  Here's what the instructions say on the tool:

> Use the directory tree to browse and select the specific subdirectory. When the specific subdirectory is listed under Current Path, you can click the button to Install Application or Remove Application.

Create a new directory for each of your applications (webapp1, webapp2, webapp3), then select each one in turn and click on "Install Application".  The directory will be turned into an application starting point.  From there you should be able to modify the application settings for each one to satisfy the needs of the particular application.

Comment: @peter I added the first web app and it works. I also did the folder for the second web app. What settings would I use (server, site path, destination url) when publishing the second web app, would they be the same as the first?

Comment: "publishing"? Using what?  I don't typically use any publishing mechanism. I usually just FTP to hosts.  It's been a while since I've pushed anything to a DiscountASP.net host, though I still have access to an account there.